# less gap between \marginnote and content after \leftskip

Tags: horizontal-alignment, margins

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=1.5in,top=0.5in,right=1.5in,bottom=0.8in, marginparsep=1pt, marginparwidth=1in}

\usepackage{marginnote}
\newcommand{\years}[1]{{\setlength{\marginparwidth}{2.5in}\marginnote{\normalsize #1}}}
\renewcommand*{\raggedleftmarginnote}{}
\reversemarginpar


\begin{document}
\leftskip1in
{\LARGE Albert Einstein}\\[1cm]

\section*{Appointments held}
\noindent
\years{1903 - 1908}Swiss Patent Office, Bern\\
\years{1908 - 1911}University of Bern\\
\years{1911 - 1912}University of Zürich\\
\years{1912 - 1914}Charles University of Prague\\
\years{1914 - 1932}Prussian Academy of Sciences, Berlin\\
\years{1920 - 1930}University of Leiden\\
\years{1932 - 1955}Institute for Advanced Study, Princeton

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the marginnote are too far from the content, I would like to have the gap smaller. So I set `\marginparwidth` to `1.5in`:

`\newcommand{\years}[1]{{\setlength{\marginparwidth}{1.5in}\marginnote{\normalsize #1}}}`

Now I have
[image]

How do I fix it?

Comment: why are you using \leftskip?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398329/set-geometry-offset-but-keep-page-number-in-the-middle

Comment: The best I can say to this answer is that Steven at least warned you that it "breaks a host of other things". If you shift the whole text one inch to the left than a large gap to the margin is the result. You should better setup the page geometry so that it is correct for normal text and then move the page number and define a "notreallycentered" environment.

Comment: never set `\leftskip` in a latex document (you also do not need `\noindent`)

Comment: Since the whole thing (including the marginnotes) fits inside the text area, you could have just used a tabular or a bunch of `\makebox`es.

Answer (score 1):

Since you intend to overlay the text area, you should use `\rlap`. Did you really want `\marginparsep=1pt`?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=1.5in,top=0.5in,right=1.5in,bottom=0.8in, marginparsep=1pt, marginparwidth=1in}

\usepackage{marginnote}
\newcommand{\years}[1]{\marginnote{\rlap{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\marginparwidth+\leftskip}%
  {\raggedleft\normalsize #1}}}}
%\renewcommand*{\raggedleftmarginnote}{}
\reversemarginpar


\begin{document}
\leftskip1in
{\LARGE Albert Einstein}\\[1cm]

\section*{Appointments held}
\noindent
\years{1903 - 1908}Swiss Patent Office, Bern\\
\years{1908 - 1911}University of Bern\\
\years{1911 - 1912}University of Zürich\\
\years{1912 - 1914}Charles University of Prague\\
\years{1914 - 1932}Prussian Academy of Sciences, Berlin\\
\years{1920 - 1930}University of Leiden\\
\years{1932 - 1955}Institute for Advanced Study, Princeton

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong tool.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=1.5in,top=0.5in,right=1.5in,bottom=0.8in,showframe}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2} % no section number

\titleformat{\section}[block]
  {\Large\bfseries}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\hspace*{1in}}

\newcommand{\years}[1]{%
  \par\noindent
  \makebox[1in][l]{#1}%
  \ignorespaces
}


\begin{document}

\noindent\hspace*{1in}{\LARGE Albert Einstein}

\vspace{1cm}

\section{Appointments held}
\years{1903--1908} Swiss Patent Office, Bern
\years{1908--1911} University of Bern
\years{1911--1912} University of Zürich
\years{1912--1914} Charles University of Prague
\years{1914--1932} Prussian Academy of Sciences, Berlin
\years{1920--1930} University of Leiden
\years{1932--1955} Institute for Advanced Study, Princeton

\end{document}
```

The `showframe` option is just for showing the text block margins.

[image]

If you want the years to be nearer the text, change the definition of `\years` to something like

```
\newcommand{\years}[1]{%
  \par\noindent
  \makebox[1in][r]{#1\quad}%
  \ignorespaces
}
```

[image]